# QTcpSocket gets NULL after QTcpServer::nextPendingConnection()

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qtcpsocket, qtcpserver

So I have a QTcpServer here (simplified version of Qt's Fortune Server Example). It was working fine earlier. Then I moved some things around and changed some code. Now my server crashes on start. As far as I can tell, after

```
tcpSocket = tcpServer->nextPendingConnection();
```

tcpSocket remains **NULL**. Thus all calls like **tcpSocket->anyCall()** will cause a seg fault. Application output shows:

```
QObject::connect: invalid null parameter
```

So my question is, why is tcpServer->nextPendingConnection() returning **NULL**
 all of a sudden, when before I moved things around it worked just fine?

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QtNetwork>
#include "server.h"

Server::Server(QWidget *parent)
: QDialog(parent), statusLabel(new QLabel), tcpServer(Q_NULLPTR), tcpSocket(Q_NULLPTR), networkSession(0), blockSize(0), userAuthenticated(false)
{
    QNetworkConfigurationManager manager;
    QNetworkConfiguration config = manager.defaultConfiguration();
    networkSession = new QNetworkSession(config, this);
    sessionOpened();

    ...
    // GUI stuff here //
    ...

    this->read_newClient();
}

void Server::sessionOpened()
{
    tcpServer = new QTcpServer(this);

    // some if else checks here //

    tcpSocket = tcpServer->nextPendingConnection(); // problem here //
    connect(tcpSocket, &QAbstractSocket::disconnected, tcpSocket, &QObject::deleteLater); // line that crashes //
}

void Server::read_newClient()
{
    QString data;
    if (!clientSocket->waitForReadyRead())
    {
        qDebug() << "Cannot read";
        return;
    }
    data = readData();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To use nextPendingConnection you need incomming connection. Therefore you have two ways:

1. Connect to signal newConnection():

   ```
   ...
   connect(tcpServer, &QTcpServer::newConnection, this, &Server::OnNewConnection);
   ...
   void Server::OnNewConnection() {
       if (tcpServer->hasPendingConnections()) {
           tcpSocket = tcpServer->nextPendingConnection();
           connect(tcpSocket, &QAbstractSocket::disconnected, tcpSocket, QObject::deleteLater);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Or use blocking call waitForNewConnection():

   ```
   if (tcpServer->waitForNewConnection()) {
       if (tcpServer->hasPendingConnections()) {
           tcpSocket = tcpServer->nextPendingConnection();
           connect(tcpSocket, &QAbstractSocket::disconnected, tcpSocket, QObject::deleteLater);
       }
   }
   ```

Do not forget call `tcpServer->listen();`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Btw I did not understand the last argument to your connect call. Also, I was missing networkSession->open();

Comment: @Deedaus QTcpServer can operate independently of networkSession.

Comment: So the whole part with manager, config and networkSession can be dropped? Why do they use it then in the Fortune example?

Comment: @Deedaus In Fortune example they also illustrates operations with network configuration(saving, reading). But minimal example for QTcpServer: http://pastebin.com/WCVsNCS5